# SpeechSynthesizer text to speech as an input i.e through the microphone

Tags: c#, winforms, audio, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

Is it possible to use the MS speechSynthesiser library and set the output of a text to speech as an audio input? If so, how would you do this. If it is not what library would I have to use and how would I do that?

if it is not very clear (sorry about that) what I want is for the speech synthesizer to talk through the microphone.
Here is my code so far to switch output paths:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     isLineOut = !isLineOut;
     if (isLineOut)
     {
         button3.Text = "LineOut";
         synth.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice();
     }
     else
     {
         button3.Text = "LineIn";
         //set speech output to line in
     }
}
```

Comment: Curious as to why you want the speech synthesizer talking to itself?

Comment: no what i want is the text to speech to output into the audio input. this is so i can use it to talk to other people. the synthesizer doesn't use audio input, it uses text input

Comment: Can your provide a clear explanation of what you need help with?

Comment: essentially i want to input text and for the synthesizer to talk through the microphone

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score -1):

we solved this for using our synthesiser with Skype

https://www.cereproc.com/en/CereProc_TTS_in_Skype

Comment: that only works for Skype i just want a general solution to put audio out into the mic. I want it in my program I don't want to use some third party to do it for me.